# Passing Core Data FetchedResults<T> for previews in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a parent view which does a `@FetchRequest` and passes the `FetchedResults<T>` to a child view. Everything works, and the child view is able to parse through the `FetchedResults`. However, I can't figure out how to set up the data so that the child's `Preview` struct will work. What's the proper way to set up some constant data in `Preview` struct so that I can instantiate the child view and pass in `FetchedResults<T>`?

Comment: I realize I can do the fetch request within the child view itself, and most examples I find online are doing that. However, I want to avoid doing that extra query.

Answer (score 13):

As `FetchedResults<T>` is a `RandomAccessCollection` and swift array also is a `RandomAccessCollection`, here is possible solution.

### Update: verified with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: Person.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
        var result: FetchedResults<Person>

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Persons").font(.title)
            PersonsView(results: result) // FetchedResults<Person> is a collection
        }
    }
}

// generalize PersonsView to depend just on collection
struct PersonsView<Results:RandomAccessCollection>: View where Results.Element == Person {
    let results: Results
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(results, id: \.self) { person in
            Text("Name: \(person.name ?? "<unknown>")")
        }
    }
}

// Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4
// DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE !!
// struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
//    static var previews: some View {
//        PersonsView(results: [Person()]) // << use regular array //to test
//    }
}
```

**Update:** fixed & tested part for Xcode 12 / iSO 14 (due to crash of above PreviewProvider)

It appears entity now should be read & specified explicitly:

```
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let entity = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: nil)?.entitiesByName["Person"]

    static var previews: some View {
        let person = Person(entity: entity!, insertInto: nil)
        person.name = "Test Name"

        return PersonsView(results: [person])
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this in both Xcode 11.6 and the 12.0 beta and the preview panel crashes every time. I'd love to have this working, any idea what might be happening in more recent builds of Xcode?

Comment: @Asperi thanks, it's working fine for a FetchedResults. I'm trying to do the same for a SectionedFetchResult but I don't understand how to deal with this. Can you help please?

Answer (score 8):

Use the **preview** PersistenceController within your pre-generated PersistenceController struct (inside the "Persistence.swift" file).

so if you pass an item from a Core Data "Item"-entity:

```
struct ContentView: View {
...
private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
..
ForEach(items) { item in
DetailView(item: item)
}
..
```

In the Detail-View go like this:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var item: FetchedResults<Item>.Element
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Items text = \(item.text ?? "")")
    }
}

struct Detail_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        let viewContext = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
        let previewItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        previewItem.text = "Text4preview"
        
        return Detail(item: previewItem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this use case as well. In my example, I have a `MoviesListView`, which is a **child view** of my `ContentView`. My `ContentView` utilizes the `@FetchRequest` property wrapper to automatically load the movies from Core Data and then provides the `FetchedResults<Movie>` to the `MoviesListView` child view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var movies: FetchedResults<Movie>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MoviesListView(movies: movies)
                .navigationTitle("Movies")
        }
    }
}
```

Originally, I was hoping I could just `let previewMovies = FetchedResults<Movie>()` to create a list of movies in the preview and pass it into the child view, but there doesn't appear to be an initializer publicly available for `FetchedResults<T>`.

To solve this, I implemented a [solution provided by Azam Sharp](https://youtu.be/ZqazqUMC-9k?si=VTCHwwcL_Y4hFjbA), which is to create a lightweight container view inside of the preview that will perform the same duties of the content view to fetch the movies from Core Data and provide them to the child view. Here is what that preview code looks for my `MoviesListView` child view:

```swift
struct MoviesListView: View {

    let movies: FetchedResults<Movie>
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(movies) { movie in
                NavigationLink {
                    MovieDetailView(movie: movie)
                } label: {
                    Text(movie.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MoviesListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    struct MoviesListViewContainer: View {
        @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var movies: FetchedResults<Movie>
        
        var body: some View {
            MoviesListView(movies: movies)
        }
    }
    
    static var previews: some View {
        MoviesListViewContainer()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PreviewDataController.moc)
    }
}
```

The final piece of the puzzle is my `PreviewDataController`, which sets up an in-memory only Core Data store for my SwiftUI previews, based on [this post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/100-days-of-swiftui/day55-making-previews-work-for-detailview/14794/16800).

Overall, I like this solution better than [the one provided by Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61495490/4343618) because it doesn't require me to modify or restructure my child view for the sake of making it work nicely with SwiftUI Previews. The container view code is also neatly tucked away inside of the preview itself, which means it's not in the same realm as my production code.

**Final Note:** I paired down these code samples from my actual code so I make no guarantees on their syntax correctness!