# SwiftUI: passing Core Data SectionedFetchResults for Previews

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data

I have a parent view which does a `@SectionedFetchRequest` and passes the `SectionedFetchResults` to a child view. Everything works, and the child view is able to parse through the `SectionedFetchResults`. However, I can't figure out how to set up the data so that the child's Previews struct will work. What's the proper way to set up some constant data in Previews struct so that I can instantiate the child view and pass in `SectionedFetchResults`?

See this similar question for a FetchedResults: [Passing Core Data FetchedResults for previews in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495141/passing-core-data-fetchedresultst-for-previews-in-swiftui/61495490#61495490)

Answer (score 0):

Use your `PersistentController.preview.container.viewContext` and preview the `View` with the `@SectionedFetchRequest`.

Comment: I want an approach without Core Data for the Views. Something like what is described in this WWDC video where rich models are not used in the Views: Structure your app for SwiftUI previews (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10149).

Comment: I was actually going to suggest that but your requirement was to pass the rich models in.